# minecraft modding setting up error

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I started setting up my mod, (FML events client/server classes) but it gave me this error when I started minecraft:

```
---- Minecraft Crash Report ----
// You should try our sister game, Minceraft!

Time: 27-4-17 10:02
Description: There was a severe problem during mod loading that has caused the game to fail

net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderExceptionModCrash: Caught exception from Eagles Toolbox (eagtools)
Caused by: net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoaderException: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eagle.eagtools.proxy.ClientProxy.java
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ProxyInjector.inject(ProxyInjector.java:88)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLModContainer.constructMod(FMLModContainer.java:595)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.sendEventToModContainer(LoadController.java:243)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.propogateStateMessage(LoadController.java:221)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventSubscriber.handleEvent(EventSubscriber.java:74)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.SynchronizedEventSubscriber.handleEvent(SynchronizedEventSubscriber.java:47)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatch(EventBus.java:322)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.dispatchQueuedEvents(EventBus.java:304)
    at com.google.common.eventbus.EventBus.post(EventBus.java:275)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.LoadController.distributeStateMessage(LoadController.java:145)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.Loader.loadMods(Loader.java:559)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.client.FMLClientHandler.beginMinecraftLoading(FMLClientHandler.java:220)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.startGame(Minecraft.java:477)
    at net.minecraft.client.Minecraft.run(Minecraft.java:386)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(Main.java:118)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:135)
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.gradle.GradleStartCommon.launch(GradleStartCommon.java:97)
    at GradleStart.main(GradleStart.java:26)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.eagle.eagtools.proxy.ClientProxy.java
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:191)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ModClassLoader.loadClass(ModClassLoader.java:75)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Unknown Source)
    at net.minecraftforge.fml.common.ProxyInjector.inject(ProxyInjector.java:71)
    ... 39 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.LaunchClassLoader.findClass(LaunchClassLoader.java:182)
    ... 45 more`
```

### A detailed walkthrough of the error, its code path and all known details is as follows:

```
-- System Details --
Details:
    Minecraft Version: 1.10.2
    Operating System: Windows 10 (amd64) version 10.0
    Java Version: 1.8.0_131, Oracle Corporation
    Java VM Version: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (mixed mode), Oracle Corporation
    Memory: 678263960 bytes (646 MB) / 1038876672 bytes (990 MB) up to 1038876672 bytes (990 MB)
    JVM Flags: 3 total; -Xincgc -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M
    IntCache: cache: 0, tcache: 0, allocated: 0, tallocated: 0
    FML: MCP 9.32 Powered by Forge 12.18.3.2281 4 mods loaded, 4 mods active
    States: 'U' = Unloaded 'L' = Loaded 'C' = Constructed 'H' = Pre-initialized 'I' = Initialized 'J' = Post-initialized 'A' = Available 'D' = Disabled 'E' = Errored
    UC  mcp{9.19} [Minecraft Coder Pack] (minecraft.jar) 
    UC  FML{8.0.99.99} [Forge Mod Loader] (forgeSrc-1.10.2-12.18.3.2281.jar) 
    UC  Forge{12.18.3.2281} [Minecraft Forge] (forgeSrc-1.10.2-12.18.3.2281.jar) 
    UE  eagtools{1.0 BETA} [Eagles Toolbox] (bin) 
    Loaded coremods (and transformers): 
    GL info: ' Vendor: 'Intel' Version: '4.4.0 - Build 21.20.16.4534' Renderer: 'Intel(R) HD Graphics 620'
```

I think the problem might be in the client class, but I can't find it.

The file: https://www.dropbox.com/s/zi540wq8ycoghoz/modding.zip?dl=0

Comment: By the way, most people aren't going to download a zip file containing your code. You'd be better off learning to use GitHub and hosting your code there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your Variables class

```
public static final String CLIENTCLASS = "com.eagle.eagtools.proxy.ClientProxy.java";
public static final String SERVERCLASS = "com.eagle.eagtools.proxy.ServerProxy.java";
```

it should be

```
public static final String CLIENTCLASS = "com.eagle.eagtools.proxy.ClientProxy";
public static final String SERVERCLASS = "com.eagle.eagtools.proxy.ServerProxy";
```